# MySQL order by "id" first then by "date"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to order my table by active campaign first followed with the "endDate". Which means, new created campaigns will always be on top followed by the date. When the campaign ends, I want the latest "endDate" to be on top.

Here's my query below:

```
SELECT   campaignId, 
         status, 
         dateCreated, 
         startDate, 
         endDate 
FROM     campaign 
WHERE    deleted='False' 
ORDER BY DATE(endDate) > DATE(CURDATE()) DESC, campaignId DESC
```

Looking at the screenshot below, some are not ordered by the "endDate" (highlighted with red box)
[image]

The first part is correct, which means the "endDate" haven't ends and is sorted by id first. However, the last part is wrong, ended campaigns should be sorted by the "endDate". Where I did wrong ?

Update SQL Fiddle (Please ignore  `WHERE deleted='False'` when using) : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a7afb

Comment: Please create a fiddle on http://sqlfiddle.com with the table structure and the sample data along with the expected result into the question.

Comment: It is created... please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using "CASE" statement. Just in case someone find this useful.

```
    SELECT 
     campaignId, status, dateCreated, startDate, endDate 
   FROM campaign 
   WHERE 
       deleted='False' 
   ORDER BY 
       CASE WHEN endDate > CURDATE() THEN campaignId END DESC, 
       CASE WHEN endDate < CURDATE() THEN DATE(endDate) END DESC
```

Comment: To mark this question as solved, please click on the tick icon adjacent to the answer you most prefer. It is fine to tick your own answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY DATE(endDate) > DATE(CURDATE()) DESC` says that future campaigns go first. It does not say in which order. Add the expression into the select clause and you will see.

You can do `ORDER BY DATE(endDate) > DATE(CURDATE()) DESC, endDate DESC, campaignId DESC`, but the `DATE(endDate) > DATE(CURDATE())` expression makes sorting very slow and prevents use of an index. Moreover, you don't have to do `DATE()` on a date column.

If you want separate list of future campaigns and past campaigns, you better do two queries, putting the endDate condition into `where` clause. However, for small datasets it does not matter.

Comment: I tried the above query u provide, it's not working also, it just sort the end date.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
     campaignId, status, dateCreated, startDate, endDate 
   FROM campaign 
   WHERE 
       deleted='False' 
   ORDER BY 
       DATE(endDate) DESC, campaignId DESC
```

This should work.

Basically you don't need  **>** condition in order by.

If you want to have filter for date greater than current date then it should be in where condition.

Comment: can you give sqlfiddle example?

Comment: added above, please have a look and ignore  WHERE  deleted='False'

Comment: Here's the logic, if enddate is higher than current date, sort by id DESC....... if enddate is lower than current date, sort by enddate DESC